# Using _.each with promise object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I'm using underscore on the data returned from a promise in my Angular controller. What caught my attention while testing through Karma was that `_.capitalize` is failing when run with `$$state` as an input.
How do I clean up the below controller code so only my data is being handled by my underscore functions, and not other promise objects?

```
var getLimits = function() {
  usersService.getLimits({
    userId: userId
  }).$promise.then(function(data) {
    _.each(data, function(activity, activityKey) {
      _.each(activity, function(limit, limitKey) {
        vm[activityKey + _.capitalize(limitKey) +'Units'] = limit.units;
      });
    });
  });
};
```

object structure:

```
{
  "score": {
    "cap": {
      "units": 300000
    },
    "floor": {
      "units": 0
    }
  },
...
}
```

Comment: are the properties with your activity objects the same each time, or will they vary?

Comment: @lwalden, they are the same.

Comment: What "other promise objects" are you talking about?

Comment: @Bergi, `$promise` which itself has a `$$state` object; `_.each` iterates over `$promise` along with my three data objects, which is less than ideal.

Comment: Can you show your implimentation of usersService.getLimits? Unfamiliar with that use of $promise - typically with Angular you would use myMethodTheReturnsAPromise(dataIn).then(function (dataReturnedByPromise)....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return only data from Angular promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487823/return-only-data-from-angular-promise)

Comment: try `_.each(data.data...`